# Get selected value from SelectItemList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to use `SelectListItem` for an MVC project, drop down is populated as I expect it. But when I pass the *selected value* to a function that accepts string using this `model.CodeDropDown.ToString()` I get `System.Collections.Generic.List 1[System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem]` which is not a string.

How can I get the selected value as string?

I have a `ViewModel` class that looks like this:

```
public class HomeViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Code")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CodeDropDown { get; set; }
    public string SelectedValue { get; set; }
}
```

I'm filling up the dropdown using this `Controller`

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new HomeViewModel();
    using (var dbCon = new SomeDBContext())
    {
       model.CodeDropDown = dbCon.CodeID.ToList().Select(x => new SelectListItem
       {
          Value = x.Name.ToString(), Text = x.CodeDropDown.ToString()
            }).DistinctBy(c => c.Value);
       }
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use the value from `SelectListItem` like this,

```
public ActionResult Index(HomeViewModel model)
    {
        var results = mainDbContext.GetSomeResult(model.CodeDropDown.ToString(), model.Prop2, model.Prop3);         
      return View(results);
    }
```

View looks like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedValue, Model.CodeDropDown, "--")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one more property (SelectedThingId or something more meaningful) to your HomeViewModel to hold the value of the selected thing from the dropdown.

In your view (you have not posted code for view) have something like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.SelectedThingId, Model.CodeDropDown)
```

Then in your controller you can get this value using:

```
model.SelectedThingId; // model is passed into your controller has you have it.
```

Comment: Is that value of `SelectedThingID` passed automatically?

Comment: Yes this line will take care of it for you: @Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.SelectedThingId, Model.CodeDropDown). This is telling the MVC view engine (Razor etc.) to create a dropdown and fill it with data from Model.CodeDropDown and whenever a selection is made record it in the SelectedThingId. Razor will write all the required html and javascript for this.

Comment: Still not getting the desired result. Look at update.

Comment: because you have not changed the code in your controller. You are still reading the value of CodeDropdown you need to access the SelectedValue instead.

Comment: Works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add 2 properties in the model

```
public string CodedropdownID{ get; set; } //to store the selected dropdown value Id
public string CodedropdownText{ get; set; } //to store the selected dropdown value text
```

Change the View as following and add onchange event to dropdown:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=> m.CodedropdownID, m.CodeDropDown, "--")
@Html.Hiddenfor(m=>m.CodedropdownText)
```

Add the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#CodedropdownID").on("change", function {
   $("#CodedropdownText").val($(this).text());
 });

</script>
```

Change the controller method

```
 public ActionResult Index(HomeViewModel model)
    {
        var results = mainDbContext.GetSomeResult(model.CodedropdownText.ToString(), model.Prop2, model.Prop3);         
      return View(results);
    }
```

Comment: Using JS we are getting the text of dropdown value on dropdown change, then we are storing the text as hidden value

Comment: If you are going to use only CodedropdownID then you will just get the ID of the selected dropdown not the string value.